# Passing Enum types as optional parameters

Tags: vb.net

When working with optional arguments, I like to default them to `Nothing`.

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal Foo as String, Optional ByVal Bar as String = Nothing)
    If Bar IsNot Nothing then DoSomethingElse(Bar)
    DoAnotherThing(Foo)
End Sub
```

This works great, unless you start working with `Enum` types (or an `Integer` and other Data types).
In which case my `Enum` list includes a 'None' value, as follows:

```
Enum MyEnum
    None
    ChoiceA
    ChoiceB
End Enum
Sub DoSomething(ByVal Foo as String, Optional ByVal Bar as MyEnum= MyEnum.None)
    If Bar = MyEnum.None then DoSomethingElse(Bar)
    DoAnotherThing(Foo)
End Sub
```

It works, but I am looking for alternatives. In addition to the burden of creating a 'None' entry in a custom `Enum`, this is just not possible to do with enumerations defined by the framework or a third party DLL.

Comment: A nullable parameter would be an alternative, `As MyEnum? = Nothing`.

Comment: `ByVal Foo as String, Optional ByVal Bar As MyEnum? = Nothing` would work, because the underlying type that is used to declare an enumeration cannot be nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case, I went across a few answers as I was drafting the question.

This [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2009/11/07/vb-net-10-optional-nullable-parameter/) and the [.NetDocumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types) suggest the use of a nullable:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal Foo as String, Optional ByVal Bar as Nullable(Of MyEnum) = Nothing)
    If Bar IsNot Nothing then DoSomethingElse(Bar)
    DoAnotherThing(Foo)
End Sub
```

Or,

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal Foo as String, Optional ByVal Bar as Nullable(Of MyEnum) = Nothing)
    If Bar IsNot Nothing then DoSomethingElse(Bar)
    DoAnotherThing(Foo)
End Sub
```

Never used this so any comments / warnings going this way are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it could make more sense to overload.

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal Foo as String, ByVal Bar as MyEnum)
    DoSomethingWithBar(Bar)
    DoSomething(Foo)
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(ByVal Foo as String)
    ' Do something with Foo
End Sub
```

Comment: I do use overloads extensively in some intances, but there are cases where the benefits of an `Optional` win. Generally speaking I find overloads reduce readability and make code maintenance more prone to errors. Having said that, it has the benefit of providing distinct XML documentation tags.

Comment: @Ama you also don't have a None, Nullable and If.

Comment: This definitely is an advantage towards None. If `Nullable` was not an alternative, I would go for overloading.